# Difference of ViewBag and ViewState in Mvc C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewstate, viewbag

I want to understand what is `ViewBag` and `ViewState` and when each of them are used. Need an explanation in code.

Comment: View State is for  *non-MVC* ASP.NET "WebForms". View State compromises state stored across post-backs via a HIDDEN field. It is *not* comparable to the View Bag in MVC which is "new each request". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623229/what-is-the-equivalent-of-viewstate-in-asp-net-mvc for MVC alternatives for persisting state. Google - really the resources available that are located by such - will answer such broad non-focused questions; as such this is too broad.

Comment: Did you google it before you asked the question here? There's many examples and explanations out there already

Comment: Here's a good one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661171/difference-between-viewbag-and-viewstate

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647562/should-i-always-use-a-view-model-or-is-it-ok-to-use-viewdata/31647765#31647765

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ViewState** is an old classic `ASP.NET WebForms` concept when controls and ASPX pages save their state between HTTP requests using a hidden field.

**ViewBag** is a completely different concept in `ASP.NET MVC` applications. It's just a simple container that you can use to pass some data from Controller to a View. This state doesn't live between HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2):

**Coming to your Question**

In MVC we dont have Viewstate.In order to maintain the values refer below link

[Maintaining viewstate in Asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285547/maintaining-viewstate-in-asp-net-mvc)

[ASP.NET MVC doesn't work with ViewState and Postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366151/asp-net-mvc-doesnt-work-with-viewstate-and-postback)

we use ViewBag,ViewData,TempData for the flow of values from controller to view or controller to controller .